# Scripting Sysprep

Tags: scripting, sysprep

I'm trying to create a script that will automate the sysprep process but I'm running into issues with the reg add command. I keep getting Invalid Syntax even though everything looks correct according to the `reg add /?` command.

Here's the script:

```
reg add HKLM\SYSTEM\Setup\Status\Sysprepstatus /v CleanupState /t REG_DWORD /d 00000002

reg add HKLM\SYSTEM\Setup\Status\Sysprepstatus /v GeneralizationState /t REG_DWORD /d 00000007

reg add HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\SoftwareProtectionPlatform /v SkipRearm /t REG_DWORD /d 00000001

msdtc -uninstall

timeout 120

msdtc -install

timeout 120

"C:\Windows\System32\Sysprep.exe" /oobe /generalize /shutdown
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: can you change those keys manually using `regedit`? Some parts of `HKLM\System` are protected.

Answer (score 1):

The reg add command works for me, however cmd is running as an Administrator.  That might be what's causing you problems.